# Facebook debug tool giving Bad Response Code (redirect) for my site

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Today, I tried to post a link from my website on my wall, but no OG meta information was fetched. Therefore, I went on to [Facebook URL Linter](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) to check things for myself and see if OG meta tags are fetched properly.

To my surprise, every link on my website including the domain itself, generated **Response code: 302**.

My OG tags are well set and they were working fine a few days ago. Following is what the debugger shows for my domain : http://www.price-tag.org

> Response Code:    302
>
> Fetched URL:  http://price-tag.org/
>
> Canonical URL:    http://price-tag.org/
>
> Final URL:    http://price-tag.org/WpjZW/

For every page from my website, facebook linter is adding an arbitrary string like above **WpjZW**.

Please let me know if this is a facebook error or something has gone wrong at my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the linter is being sent on a circular redirect loop.  It is seeing a 302 redirect.

For http://www.price-tag.org I don't see anything but a 200 response code when I navigate to your website using Firefox.

However, if I remove the www from the url and go to http://price-tag.org, I do see the strange behaviour of the 302s and then a random url like http://price-tag.org/UKXRN/

I would suggest you contact your server admin or web master to see what they have in place that is doing this 302 redirect and strange url characters.

Comment: I too am confused is there something wrong with my provider or facebook.... I have mailed them , but don't expect much because they(godaddy) mostly say "things are good at our friend"....

Comment: You should log into your GoDaddy account check your DNS settings on your domain and ensure the @A record is correct. And ensure the * is set correctly to allow both the www. and non www. version to work the same. Also be sure you're not using any URL redirectors.

Comment: I am able to visit the website by typing http://price-tag.org in browser. The redirection is happening just for the facebook debug tool....Also, the http://www.price-tag.org is showing redirect response in linter......I never changed anything in DNS and earlier it was working fine.....Have mailed them, lets when they reply me

Comment: I see the redirection happening in my browser, so it's not just the linter!  You should be able to manage your own DNS settings via GoDaddy.  I have three domains with them, so I know it's possible.

Comment: To be honest, I have very less knowledge about the DNS management, so I rarely log into it....Here's link to the image of my [DNS Screen](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/39/dnsta.jpg/).....Point out if you see any problems

Comment: I found this: http://support.godaddy.com/groups/domains-management-and-services/forum/topic/http-302-redirect-error-instead-of-http-200-ok/  Looks like it is a current issue with them. I would suggest adding a me-too to the support thread there.  And you should call them too.

Comment: I mailed them 8 hours ago and now have added a "me too" to the link provided by you....lets hope they solve the problem or atleast give an answer

Comment: This is their answer **The 302 redirects are filters setup to maintain the integrity of the hosting server while we investigate and resolve an issue(s).** ...To be honest this is really bad....To maintain their servers, they can't just hurt other customers....extremely poor excuse for such an important thing....Like you, other people might have visited my site and found a 302 response...I am not sure if they gonna ever come back....Pathetic excuse from godaddy

Comment: Just because you don't understand the technical nature of the workaround doesn't make it pathetic.

Comment: May be, I was bit rational and emotional for a moment as i have been too involved in coding and getting this site up for last few days :-) .... Anyways will read into this thing bit more... and thanks :-)

Comment: Remember, they could either take the servers out of rotation or have the workaround. My vote is for the temporary workaround.  I really do hope the issue is resolved soon too!!!

Comment: DMCS, it will be four days in few hours and still the redirection is happening. May be, I am not that aware about the technical aspects about Web Servers, but nothing takes this much time.....They just mailed me the same reply and don't know what kind of integrity are they maintaining for all this while :-)